# All possible Wired communication protocols that also transmit power supply in IoT

Tags: standards, power-sources

I am on the lookout for Wired networks deployed in Industrial and other IoT applicable sectors which use cables to transfer **Power + Data**.

I am aware of:

1. Power over Ethernet (PoE) IEEE standard which sends information and power (48V) over the same CAT5/CAT5e cables so end nodes do not require separate power source.

However I only see this standard for practical applications and widely used throughout many sectors. I am curious which other standards are there juxaposing with PoE or competing with it?

Since CAN is widely used in industries, is there something like *Power over CAN* ?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Only power in the same cable together with data (very common) or data over the same wires as power?

Comment: I am interested in the former.

Comment: Then it is not a question of the protocol, but of the cable. Of course, the cable has to fulfill certain properties to allow for high-speed data transmission, but there are many products available in that area. Just to give one example: The 
UNITRONIC BUS PB FD Y HYBRID by LAPP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a very general question, not really specific to IoT at all. If you were looking for a specific power/data combination, that would be more relevant, but this looks like a general research question.

Comment: x10 comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

As you know PoE is used in practical devices such as:

- IP cameras
- VoIP Phones
- Wireless Access points
- etc.

but I'm assuming what you want to know is other standards similar to PoE for passing data and power.

In that case you should take a look at KNX standard, there is wide list of devices using this standard and commonly used for Smart Homes and IoT purposes.

As stated in the [KNX Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNX_(standard)#KNX_standard):

> The KNX standard has been built on the OSI-based EIB communication
> stack extended with the physical layers, configuration modes and
> application experience of BatiBUS and EHS.
>
> KNX installations can use several physical communication media:
>
> - Twisted pair wiring (inherited from the BatiBUS and EIB Instabus
>   standards)
> - Power-line networking (inherited from EIB and EHS - similar
>   to that used by X10) Radio (KNX-RF) based on Z-Wave protocols
> - Infrared
> - Ethernet (also referred to as EIBnet/IP or KNXnet/IP)
>
> KNX is not based
> on a specific hardware platform and a network can be controlled by
> anything from an 8-bit microcontroller to a PC, according to the
> demands of a particular building. The most common form of installation
> is over twisted pair medium.